# Android OpenGL fragment shader resolution

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a fragment shader that's running at about 25fps. If the screen were lower resolution I'm guessing that the shader would run faster. Is there any way to convince my shader it's running on a lower resolution screen? So essentially sacrifice detail - the output would be blockier - in order to gain performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are other optimization you can do (like rendering less primitives)

but if you want to render at a lower resolution then you should first render to a lower resolution offscreen framebuffer and then re-render with that buffer as a texture on a fullscreen quad at full resolution

edit: looking at your code you can do the following:

1. move the code to the vertex shader and pass the result to a `varrying vec3 f_color` output which you set the gl_FragColor to in the fragment shader
2. make a uniform grid of triangles between -1,-1 and 1,1 where the amount of triangles depends on your desired resolution
3. draw that grid

Comment: Thanks. Sounds a bit beyond me for now. Was hoping there was a solution like process-every-tenth-xy. See my response to Rick77.

Comment: Just to let you know I implemented your vertex suggestion and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the tone of the request I *assume* you are sort of new about OpenGL (as the request about the resolution is pretty basic, no disregard intended, we all started some way): the answer by ratchet freak is correct (->render on a texture on low resolution and then just display the texture on the screen is the direct answer to your question about resolution) however, as ratchet freak also hinted, you should probably look elsewhere for a way to solve your problem (as lowering the resolution of your fragment shader will really make your output look **bad**™ ).

Some hints:

- try to do as much as you can in the vertex shader: many computation can be executed per vertex in the vertex shader and then sent (with interpolation) to the fragment shader. This is a **huge** source of optimisation and should be exploited every time it's possible
- search your fragment shader for cycles and conditionals (if/then), particularly cycles that cannot be unrolled (variable ranges) and conditionals that doesn't depend from uniforms, as they are both quite taxing at a fragment shader level
- render less primitives if possible
- if you are using a lot of complex functions (cos/sin/sqrt etc) try caching the results and/or using lookup tables (if possible)
- enable culling and depth testing to reduce the amount of geometry rasterized [not sure if it will help, will not hurt, though ;-) ]
- lower the precision of some computations, if the result doesn't degrade doing so

You can try posting your fragment shader in your question

Hope this helps

Comment: Yep, you're right ... very new to OpenGL. I've implemented this fragment shader - https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldBGRR - on my Nexus 7 to try just as a starter. It runs at 26 fps. I appreciate there's loads of trig processing in there but just wondering if I needed to run it for every single xy.

Comment: @jFort openGL runs it for every xy regardless, but you can optimise it a bit by splitting the field up in a grid and computing the color once per vertex in the vertex shader and then letting openGL interpolate for the fragment shader

Comment: @jFort: do you mean "trigonometry" with "trig"? If so it very likely that the computation should be moved to the vertex shader. Same goes for lighting models (unless you are going for super realistic lighting, in which case reducing the resolution is a no-go anyway... you are prob. better with a simpler lighting model and full res.): normals, light and view vectors should be computed in the vertex shader and "exported" to the fragment shader with some varying. Just be vary that during the interpolation you will likely need to re-normalize the vectors in the fragment s.